# converting string listview to custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio

I've created a listview which shows all currently installed apps on the android device. The code also retrieves the icon of the app, but I cannot display it within the list because it can only display strings. How can I alter my code so that it also displays the app icon next to the name?

additionally after I do this I also want to add a checkbox next to each app title and icon

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    for (Object object : pkgAppsList)
    {
        ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
        Drawable icon    = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
        String strAppName   = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir.toString();
        String strPackageName  = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.toString();
        final String title  = (String)((info != null) ? getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo) : "???");
        list.add(title);
    }

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

thanks

Comment: you cannot convert normal list-view into custom list..You must create separate layout & Java class. for more info:http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2012%2F02%2Fandroid-custom-listview-with-image-and-text%2F&ei=jjAQVdmyDdSKuASAoYKIAg&usg=AFQjCNHsk11ptgks53a2ymPMCZRb-AA2Zw&bvm=bv.88528373,d.c2E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 things:

1. a single row layout
2. a class to store your App-Name & Icon
3. a custom list adapter

custom_row_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/nav_item_bg"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AppDetails.java

```
public class AppDetails {
    String name;
    Drawable icon;

    public AppDetails(String name, Drawable icon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

AppDetailsAdapter.java

```
public class AppDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<AppDetails> data;
private Context context;

public AppDetailsAdapter(Context context, List<AppDetails> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_layout, null);
    }

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

    final AppDetails item = data.get(position);
    text.setText(item.name); 
    icon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);

    return view;
}
```

To implement this to your Code you should do something like:

```
List<AppDetails> appList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object object : pkgAppsList)
{
    //This is your foreach loop over all apps
    //.. Add these 2 line at the end of your loop
    AppDetails tmp = new AppDetails(strAppName, icon);
    appList.add(tmp)
}
```

And instead of using an exsistig ArrayAdapter you should use the one i created above by:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
AppDetailsAdapter adapter = new AppDetailsAdapter(this, appList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I've been trying to understand this but I can't see how to apply it to my code, I use a for loop to retrieve the app name and app icon, where would I place this loop in your code? Where you comment apply text? I'm not sure what you mean by "and item from the "item" object

Comment: @user3343264 Ive edited my code above. I try'd to explaine how to include in your existing code.

Comment: getting an error on public DeviceItem in app details, return type is required, not too sure how to fix

Comment: Oh sorry .. Just rename DeviceItem to AppDetails. That should to the trick

Comment: oh ok yeah. I'm just confused about where to place the code you wrote, the segment which starts with List<AppDetails> appList = new ArrayList<>(); should I place that within my loop where it retrieves the app details? and the last 2 chunks of code you wrote I don't know where to place them. I'm sorry about my ignorance on this

Comment: No you have to Initialize the appList outside your Loop. Replace the final AppDetailsAdapter adapter =...  Line of code with your "final ArrayAdapter adapter =...". The last two lines of code come inside the Adapter Class where I wrote the comment.

Comment: ok. I have 2 errors, AppDetails tmp = new AppDetails(); because it expects string and drawable in the brackets and after final AppDetailsAdapter in the brackets too, "...in apppdetailsadapter cannot be applied to java.util.list

Comment: Ok the first error: replace AppDetails tmp = new AppDetails(); with AppDetails tmp = new AppDetails(strAppName, icon); and delete the two lines tmp.name = strAppName and tmp.icon = icon. And a few more details for the second error pls. It seems you dont have many experience in android/java/oop. Maybe we should start a chat to solve your issues

Comment: ok so (this, appList); is underlined in the final AppDetailsAdapter, the message states "AppDetailsAdapter (Context, java.util.arraylist cannot be applied to (MainActivity, java.util.list<com.example.applist.AppDetails>)
And yes this is my first project that isn't simple hello worlds or anything. I apparently don't have enough points to start a chat sadly

Comment: Oh i see it. Inside this line: "public AppDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AppDetails> data){..." delete the "Array" before List -> "public AppDetailsAdapter(Context context, List<AppDetails> data){.."

Comment: thank you so much, just need to try and get my head around how exactly it all works now so I can add buttons next to each item, you're a life saver